# inconsistent Rspec/Capybara tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have commented out [get "pages/home"] in my routes.rb file, restarted my entire test environment and the following test STILL passes:

```
it "should contain 'This is a test'" do
  get 'home'
  response.body.should have_selector("p")
end
```

From my understanding, capybara runs the rspec tests from a 'browser' in memory.  If this is the case the rails routes MUST exist!  After commenting out my routes, it is still able to load the pages - I know this because if I remove the `<p>` selector the test fails.  After modifying the routes.rb file I have restarted my testing suite but it doesn't make a difference.

This makes me lose trust in the testing process because I have tests passing that shouldn't pass!!

Comment: Show us full `_spec.rb`. Perhaps you have `before(:each)` with `get 'home'` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this fragment is in a controller spec, which hits your controller directly. In the latest version of rspec, 2.9.0, a bad route won't make this example fail. Routes are outside the purview of a controller spec.

It seems like you intended to write a request spec, which should use capybara's `visit` method:

```
# spec/requests/something_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'home page' do

  it "should contain 'This is a test'" do
    visit '/pages/home'
    page.should have_content 'This is a test'
  end

end
```

See the [capybara docs](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) for more examples. Rspec also supports [routing specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs), but I usually only use those for unusual routing.

Comment: Very interesting.  So the whole time I am doing [get 'home'] inside of the 'it' block, it's not even hitting Capybara?  I thought that [get 'something'] called Capybara, but apparently it's just Rspec.  Is this correct?  And yes, that's a controller test.

Comment: Yes, capybara adds `visit`, `click_on`, `fill_in`, etc. Take a look at the capybara docs linked above for lots of examples.